# Sending async action to redux dispatch using typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I have a problem when I'm trying to dispatch an async action in redux.
I'm using redux-thunk to handle my async middlewares.

I have an async action function like this one:

```
function async() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(req());

        setTimeout(function() {
            dispatch(rec());
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

here is my createStore statement:

```
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

When Im trying to do this: `store.dispatch(async())` I'm getting this kind of error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(dispach: any) => void' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'Action'

The code itself works when I'm just using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to download the redux typings from definitelytyped:
`typings i redux --ambient`